# Relationship with TypeORM (NestJS)

Tags: javascript, mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I recently started to learn TypeORM and faced such a problem. There are 2 tables Post and PostMedia, Post - a record in which there is information and 2 links to files from the PostMedia table, PostMedia - a table in which metadata and a link to files are stored. How to properly link these 2 tables so that in the 1st post you can refer to the second table twice? (columns preview and media) Now after restarting the application, all data is erased

UPD:
We have 2 files in one (Post) entity, and a another (PostModia) entity with storage information about the storage of these files, media and previews. How to organize tables correctly?

```
@Entity()
export class Posts {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  title: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  description: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  link: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  publish: boolean;

  @OneToOne(() => PostMedia, (media) => media.post)
  @JoinColumn()
  media: PostMedia;

  @OneToOne(() => PostMedia, (media) => media.post)
  @JoinColumn()
  preview: PostMedia; 

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: string;
}
```

And PostMedia

```
@Entity()
export class PostMedia {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  url: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  mime: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Post)
  post: Post;
  //...other columns

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: string;
}
```

Comment: well i think you are try a one to one relationship were Every Post has a Post media, if I am correct?

Comment: @phemieny7 One post has only 2 files, a picture in the field (preview) and a video in the field (media). Is it correct to store all this in PostMedia or should it be done in some other way?

Comment: Well you have to put some things into perspective which is the life cycle of your files,1 uploading them, will there be a different API service for that, 2 updating the files, and 3 deleting the post and the media itself, how do you intend to handle all these.

Comment: I use my own service that creates a file, saves, deletes and returns the information that I store in the database. When updating, I just check if the file is installed, then delete it from the storage, and overwrite the new one, this is how I see it) The problem is in the models, 2 files should refer to another one model, theoretically I could make a OneToMany relation and set types for these files, but I see problems with overwriting because I need to make additional queries to the database to find the file and replace it. If you can advise on the best way to do this, I would be glad

Comment: Yeah, you just mention overwriting, and that is just what I want to hear you say, your application is too simple to be putting too much of a table to it. so I will recommend you go with a single table that has 2 file columns. Check the trend
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88938/use-a-separate-custom-table-not-posts-to-handle-file-upload-data